# Where did the Goombas come from?

Tags: mario-series

In the Super Mario series, there are little creatures called Goombas. If you haven't played Mario, this is a Goomba.

[image: a Goomba]

My question is this: Where did they come from? What inspired the Goomba? It's been in Mario since its start, so what exactly is it, and where did it come from?

Answer (score 78):

They came from the Mushroom Kingdom, being residents that joined Bowser.

> A mushroom who betrayed the Mushroom Kingdom.
> <sub>– [Super Mario Bros. manual](https://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_NES/manual/Formated/Super_Mario_Bros._-_1985_-_Nintendo.pdf#page=6)</sub>

They are inspired by mushrooms. Specifically shiitake mushrooms:

[image: shiitake mushrooms]
[image: Goomba sprite from SMB1]

> We decided that that we should make an enemy that you could easily squash with a single blow. That's why we made it so that the first enemy the player would encounter would be a Goomba. But we created it right at the very end. [...] It's a shiitake mushroom!
> <sub>– [Iwata Asks: New Super Mario Bros. Wii](https://web.archive.org/web/20091217145506/http://us.wii.com/iwata_asks/nsmb/vol2_page5.jsp)</sub>

---

As an aside, in Japanese they are called Kuribō, which means something like "chestnut person". While presumably this refers to the colour, the design in Super Mario World was of a literal chestnut rather than a mushroom.

[image: chestnuts]
[image: Goomba sprite from SMW]

---

<sub>click images to enlarge</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125043/discussion-on-answer-by-orangedog-where-did-the-goombas-come-from).